# WTForms Flask - Как установить стандартное значение value, получаемое из переменной, перед рендером?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtf

С недавнего времени я решил в своем небольшом проекте переделать все формы и перевести их на WTForms, дабы обезопасить их. Все проходило нормально до тех пор, пока мне не потребовалось во время рендеринга формы выдавать её с уже заполненными полями, данные для которых получаются из БД (а-ля настройки профиля).

Долго искал способы реализации, но так ничего не нашел (скорее всего плохо искал). В большинстве случаев описывались ситуации, когда стандартное значение нужно установить статичным т.е. `value="123"` и подобные моменты. Пробовал реализовать на костылях при помощи `form.'название поля'.data`, но в таком случае происходило именно автозаполнение и при отправке запроса на сервер, приходила форма без изменений, сделанных пользователем. Думал попробовать заменять значение value шаблонизатором, но при записи `<p>{{ form.user_name(class="ifisverify", required='required', value={{ user_name }} ) }}</p>` вторые {{}} скобки игнорируются и вместо замещаемых данных, видят выражение как строку из-за вложенности.

Кто сталкивался с подобной необходимостью установить стандартное значение поля, получаемое из переменной, перед рендерингом, объясните пропащему каким способом это можно нормально реализовать.

P.S. Только начал разбираться с WTForms и Flask в целом, так что весьма вероятно, что где-то я что-то упустил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ещё покопавшись нашел, как оказалось, простое решение проблемы. В HTML пишем:

```
{{ form.имя_поля(value=название_переменной_без_кавычек_и_скобок) }}
```

В .py:

```
render_template('название_страницы.html', название_переменной_без_кавычек_и_скобок= пермененная_из_которой_нужно_передать_сначение_jinja)
```